# Adding headers for Spring OAuth2 Client Credentials flow

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Client credentials implementation of Spring OAuth2 takes in client id and client secret for authorization to get a token. But my company requires an extra API key header to pass through the request. Is there a way to add a header to the request via Client Credentials grant type.